# Unable to generate line numbers in fpc debugging output

Tags: freepascal

I have a very simple test program (test.pas) as shown below and I'm trying to generate a memory trace but am unable to get any detailed output containing line numbers etc.

```
program test;

var
  intPointer:^integer;

begin
  new(intPointer); //Allocate some memory
  intPointer^:=5;
  // dispose(intPointer);

  WriteLn('Hello World');

end.
```

I ran the following.

```
fpc -g -gh -gl test.pas; ./test
```

And this is the output I get.

```
Hello World
Heap dump by heaptrc unit
1 memory blocks allocated : 2/8
0 memory blocks freed     : 0/0
1 unfreed memory blocks : 2
True heap size : 327680 (32 used in System startup)
True free heap : 327488
Should be : 327512
Call trace for block $00000001000CA0C0 size 2
```

In this toy example, I can tell that the `intPointer` was not disposed off, but for larger applications I was hoping for more insight. Other examples online seem to show the line number in the original file that allocated the memory, and I was wondering what I am doing incorrectly.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Added another example (subsection 9.2) that I'm unable to get line number information for.

http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/pool/tuts/FreePascal/units/node10.html

Comment: version? Target?  A new release came out a few days ago.

Comment: I'm using fpc 3.0.2 and I'm running this on osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes lineinfo can't determine source file exactly, especially for the top call in stack trace. If you would like to see the file name, you need to move your code from the main begin/end statement into a procedure. It's not ideal solution, but it makes debugging a bit easier.

```pascal
program test;

procedure PointerTest;
var
  intPointer:^integer;
begin
  new(intPointer); //Allocate some memory
  intPointer^:=5;
  // dispose(intPointer);

  WriteLn('Hello World');
end;

begin
  PointerTest;
end.
```

Also, it seems that now unit exeinfo (which is used by lineinfo) supports only [ppc32 architecture on macOS](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/master/rtl/inc/exeinfo.pp#L1233).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexey. I see get the same output when I run your code as I did before. Can you share what the output is when you run the application? 

```fpc -g -gh -gl main.pas; ./main
Hello World
Heap dump by heaptrc unit
1 memory blocks allocated : 2/8
0 memory blocks freed     : 0/0
1 unfreed memory blocks : 2
True heap size : 327680 (32 used in System startup)
True free heap : 327488
Should be : 327512
Call trace for block $00000001000CA0C0 size 2
```

There are no line numbers in the output that I get.

Comment: That's so odd. On my mac with the same compilation commands do not have the line number output.

Comment: Also you can try FPC 3.0.0. I found that it has more stable lineinfo unit.

Comment: I think I figured out at least part of my problem. 1) It does not work on Mac but this example works on my Ubuntu VM. 2) It does not work if I use a library, but only if I use a `program`.

Comment: But even if I write a custom program to include the library code I'm still unable to get line numbers for the memory leaks. I'm working with a large pascal code base so it is hard for me to make sense of what is going on exactly.

Comment: I've updated my answer - fpc lineinfo unit supports only ppc32 for mac.

Comment: Which type of library do you mean?

Comment: Ah that would explain why I'm not able to do this on my Mac. If I replace `program` with `library`, I can create a shared library successfully. I can then load this shared library using C/CPP/Python. However, I am unable to get debug information or line numbers if I do that.

Comment: Yes, tried to load a library using python code on Linux - lineinfo module doesn't work. I think the only way to test it - write unit tests and run on Linux. I recommend to use Docker for it.